# A helper named 'percentage-columns-layout' could not be found in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I installed the ember-collection addon in ember.js. While the running my app I got the following error.

**"A helper named 'percentage-columns-layout' could not be found"**

What should I do?
Please Help me.

Comment: did you just install it or use it?if you have used it, the code would be appreciated

Comment: Now I removed the ember-collection addon. I don't use it yet.But I got the error message. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: How did you install the addon? What's the version of the installed addon? What's the version of Ember CLI?

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for your reply..

Comment: What is the solution? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created percentage-columns-layout.js in helper and write the following codes.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function percentageColumnsLayout(params/*, hash*/) {
  // return params;
     return {
    /**
     * Return an object that describes the size of the content area
     */
      contentSize(clientWidth, clientHeight) {
          return { params};
      }
    }
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(percentageColumnsLayout);
```